# Android - Launching fragment passing navigation args using espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-navigation

I'm testing my fragments on espresso using something like this:

```
launchFragmentInContainer<ErrorManagerFragment>(themeResId = R.style.MaterialTheme)
```

However, my ErrorManagerFragment needs an argument and I can't figure out how to pass it to my fragment.

```
internal class ErrorManagerFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_error_manager) {

    private val navArgs: ErrorManagerFragmentArgs by navArgs()
    private val attemptNumber by lazy { navArgs.StringNumAttemptError }

    ...
}
```

I tried a couple of solutions I found on the internet but they are not working as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `NavArgs` class allows you to construct an instance directly from its values - i.e., you can use `ErrorManagerFragmentArgs(15)` to construct a `ErrorManagerFragmentArgs` instance. This can be transformed into a Bundle by using the `toBundle()` method that every Args class has, allowing you to pass that to your `launchFragmentInContainer` call:

```
val args = ErrorManagerFragmentArgs(15)
launchFragmentInContainer<ErrorManagerFragment>(
    themeResId = R.style.MaterialTheme,
    fragmentArgs = args.toBundle()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you must do is to open your NavGraph and check some information about this fragment:

```xml
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/errorManagerFragment"
    android:name="br.com.itau.oneclick.presentation.view.fragment.ErrorManagerFragment"
    android:label="fragment_manager_error"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_error_manager">
        
    <argument
        android:name="numAttemptError"
        android:defaultValue="1"
        app:argType="integer" />

</fragment>
```

Here, we must understand something interesting. String Resources does not work well with NagArgs, so the key in your bundle will not be the value to `@string/num_attempt_error`, but this string itself. You can check this by opening the `ErrorManagerFragmentArgs` class:

```kotlin
data class ErrorManagerFragmentArgs(
  val StringNumAttemptError: Int = 1
) : NavArgs {
  fun toBundle(): Bundle {
    val result = Bundle()
    result.putInt("numAttemptError", this.StringNumAttemptError)
    return result
  }

  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun fromBundle(bundle: Bundle): ErrorManagerFragmentArgs {
      bundle.setClassLoader(ErrorManagerFragmentArgs::class.java.classLoader)
      val __StringNumAttemptError : Int
      if (bundle.containsKey("numAttemptError")) {
        __StringNumAttemptError = bundle.getInt("@string/num_attempt_error")
      } else {
        __StringNumAttemptError = 1
      }
      return ErrorManagerFragmentArgs(__StringNumAttemptError)
    }
  }
}
```

Knowing that, you can pass this value to your bundle like so:

```kotlin
launchFragmentInContainer<ErrorManagerFragment>(
    themeResId = R.style.MaterialTheme,
    fragmentArgs = bundleOf("numAttemptError" to attempts)
)
```

Of course that now that you know that string resources does not work with navgraph, you should probably replace your argument name to something else.

Comment: You should never be using a string resource for an argument name; that's always the wrong thing to do.